# How do I deal with URL reroutes in Python Bottle and Apache .htaccess?

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, bottle, fastcgi

I am currently trying to create a simple standalone application using Python Bottle.

My entire project is under `pytest/`, where I have `dispatch.fcgi` and `.htaccess`.

`dispatch.fcgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import bottle
import os
from bottle import route, run, view

@route('<foo:path>')
@view('index')
def pytest(foo = ''):
    return dict(foo=foo)

APP_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.append(os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'templates'))
app = bottle.default_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

`.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex dispatch.fcgi
```

The following URLs give me the corresponding values of `foo`:

```
url.com/pytest/
> /pytest/

url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi
> /pytest/dispatch.fcgi

url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi/
> /

url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi/foo/bar
> /foo/bar

url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi/pytest/
> /pytest/
```

How can I make the URLs uniform? Should I deal with the rerouting with the `.htaccess` file or within the Python code? What would be considered most pythonic, or best practices?

I am running Python 2.6.6, Bottle 0.11.6, Flup 1.0.2, and Apache 2.2.24. I would also like to point out that I'm using shared hosting, and mod_wsgi is out of the question (if that makes a difference).

**EDIT**

This is what I expect to see:

```
url.com/pytest/
> <redirect to url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi>

url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi
> <empty string>

url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi/
> /

url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi/foo/bar
> /foo/bar

url.com/pytest/dispatch.fcgi/pytest/
> /pytest/
```

If there is a more efficient way of tackling this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Phil, what does "make the URLs uniform" mean?  You showed us the output of your current code--good--but it'd be helpful to also see the output you /expect/ to see, to make it clearer what you're trying to do and how we can help.

Comment: @ron.rothman edited to include expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottle seems to be confused because it expects a trailing slash, followed by parameters. For that reason I changed my .htaccess file to read like this:

```
DirectoryIndex dispatch.fcgi/
```

Another option would be to have all errors fall back onto the dispatch script. That can be done with `mod_rewrite`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

# rewrite for current folder
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pytest

# redirect to front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ dispatch.fcgi/ [R=301,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

or `FallbackResource`:

```
FallbackResource /pytest/dispatch.fcgi/
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts.  Hopefully some or all of these will help.

1) You can do the redirect from '/' to '/pytest/dispatch.fcgi' like this:

```
@route('/')
def home():
    bottle.redirect('/pytest/dispatch.fcgi')
```

2) Can you use ScriptAlias instead of DirectoryIndex?  I see you're on a shared environment, so I'm not sure.  My bottle/apache servers use ScriptAlias (or WSGIScriptAlias) and it works perfectly there; and it'd make more clear the way your code interacts with apache.

3) If worse came to worst, could you hackishly detect the case where foo == '/pytest/dispatch.fcgi' and act accordingly?  (E.g., treat it as empty string.)

Hope this helps.  Please keep us posted!

Comment: Thanks for your help, though it wasn't the solution I came up with. I figured out that Bottle was mostly confused if I did not add an extra slash after the fcgi file.